# Postpone local notification in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift

I have a local notification and I added an action to it. How should I do so that when the action is tapped, the local notification is fired again after 15 minutes?

Here is the code and the extension so that the notification can be showed using an UIImage:

```
extension UNNotificationAttachment {

    static func create(identifier: String, image: UIImage, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let imageFileIdentifier = identifier+".png"
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
                return nil
            }
            try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        } catch {
            print("error " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}


func scheduleNotification() {
    removeNotification()
    if shouldRemind && dueDate > Date() {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Reminder:"
        content.body = text
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: dueDate)
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: false)
        let identifier = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        if let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(identifier: identifier, image: notificationImage, options: nil) {
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        }
        let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "remindLater", title: "Remind me later", options: [])
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "category", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
        content.categoryIdentifier = "category"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "\(itemID)", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call a modified version `scheduleNotification` again in the action handler when the user activates the action. I would definitely create a function variable as a `TimeInterval` or a boolean which determines the trigger time of the notification.

Comment: I've thought of this, but how can I get the current item if the app is closed?